# wordpress plugin : settings api with OOP

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I am now using OOP to create my wordpress plugin, however i am having a problem with the Settings API,i think the third parameter (the callback function) should ECHO/PRINT a returned value from the defined function, and not make the function Echo the input, look at this for more informations : [image]

and this is the code snippet you need to look at :

```
public function another_function(){
    add_settings_field('test', 'test', $this->get_input('test', 'test', 'text'), 'test_settings', 'test_settings');
}

public function get_input($id, $name, $type, $size=40, $droparray = NULL){
    $options = get_option('brutal_settings_group');
    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
            echo '<input id="'. $id .'" name="test['. $name .']" size="'. $size .'" type="text" value="'. $options[$name] .'" />';
            break;
    }
}
```

because of the echo in the get_input function, the fields get printed above everything in every page, but if the wordpress function add_settings_field printed a returned value and not counted on a function to print it for it self, it would've worked,so how to out come this ?

Hope i got my idea clear, Best Regards

Comment: Added bounty, really need a solution asap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`add_settings_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) expects it's third argument to be a [callback](http://php.net/callback#language.types.callback), but you are actually calling your `get_input` method. In order to use the `get_input` method as a callback you need to pass an array containing the object and method name `array($this, 'get_input')`.

You can't pass arguments to directly to the method when doing this, but I think if you pass an array of values as the sixth argument to your `add_settings_field` call Wordpress will in turn pass this array to your callback when it's called. So, your `add_settings_field` call would look something like this:

```
add_settings_field(
    'test', 
    'test', 
    array($this, 'get_input'),
    'test_settings',
    'test_settings',
    array(
        'id' => 'test',
        'name' => 'test',
        'type' => 'text'
    )
);
```

You'd then need to modify your callback function to extract the values from the array, something like the below.

```
public function get_input($args) {
    $size = 40;
    $droparray = NULL;
    extract($args);
    …
```

Comment: Depending on how the arguments are passed to callback, the OP may need to remove the method arguments and use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) instead. If using PHP 5.3, an anonymous function may be an easier implementation

Comment: @Phil Good point, I've updated the answer after looking at the Wordpress source.

Comment: It is not working, the arguments are not getting passed to the get_input function, even with func_get_args()

Comment: ok i did something to test, and your way isn't working at all, instead of adding arguments, lets start with something simple : echo 'test'; in the get_input function, when we call it as callback like you did, 'test' doesn't get printed at all !

Comment: If you need more help see this example of a plugin which creates a settings page using a class: https://gist.github.com/1156867

Comment: dude, i removed the arguments, no more arguments, now i am passing a callback function that echoes "test", but test doesn't get printed...

Comment: OK, what does the rest of your plugin look like then? Look at the gist in my previous comment to see a working example of using a class to create a settings page.

Comment: ok thank you, i used the gist and it works like a charm now !, one thing, when i press save it says settings saved, but when i check in DB, or try to call them via get_option they are not there, not saved; note : even your example produces same bug...

Comment: Oh my bad, i didn't notice carefully it is working, thank you, awarded  you the bounty :D

Answer (score 1):

The value taken as a return is fed into a variable that has all of the page content. This page content is echoed out of php last and because of this anything that is echoed out will appear above it or below all of the content if the last thing you did was echo it.

Comment: yes that it what i was trying to say, meaning is you can't use class functions as callback function to add_settings_field function, atleast  that is what i know, but how to outcome this ?i mean how to use the the class function as callback...

Comment: Well you can take the content and return the value. This function is going to need to be called upon within the template.

Comment: Well you can take the content and return the value. This function is going to need to be called upon with a do action function. You can read all about hooks and the wordpress API here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about,take what content and return what value ??

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the results the way they are due to the fact that you are not successfully passing a callback to the WordPress function.  It is trying to resolve the '$this->get_input()' to pass the results to 'add_settings_field'.

In order to pass a class member function as a callback you need to pass an array with $this as reference and the function name as a string.

```
add_settings_field('test', 'test', $this->get_input('test', 'test', 'text'), 'test_settings', 'test_settings');
```

would become

```
add_settings_field('test', 'test', array(&$this, 'get_input'), 'test_settings', 'test_settings');
```

You can't pass callback arguments directly when referencing a class member function.