# How do I add fields to Settings>General in Wordpress Dashboard using OOP classes

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

The below procedural PHP code will add 5 text fields to Settings>General in the WP dashboard but how do I achieve the same with using OOP classes?

```
function link_settings_api_init() {
    // Add the section to general settings so we can add our
    // fields to it
    add_settings_section(
       'links_setting_section',
       'Social Links',
       'links_setting_section_callback_function',
       'general'
   );

    // Add the field with the names and function to use for our new
    // settings, put it in our new section
    add_settings_field(
       'facebook_link',
       'Facebook Link',
       'facebook_function',
       'general',
       'links_setting_section'
   );

   add_settings_field(
        'twitter_link',
        'Twitter Link',
        'twitter_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'linkedin_link',
        'Linkedn Link',
        'linkedin_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'instagram_link',
        'Instagram Link',
        'instagram_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'youtube_link',
        'YouTube Link',
        'youtube_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );
    // Register our setting so that $_POST handling is done for us and
    // our callback function just has to echo the <input>
    register_setting( 'general', 'facebook_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'twitter_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'linkedin_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'instagram_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'youtube_link' );

} // link_settings_api_init()

add_action( 'admin_init', 'link_settings_api_init' );

function links_setting_section_callback_function() {
    echo '<p>Add Social Media Links for HSPH</p>';
}

function facebook_function() {
$facebook_link = get_option( 'facebook_link', '' );
echo '<input id="facebook_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="Facebook Link" name="facebook_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($facebook_link) . '" />';
}

function twitter_function() {
$twitter_link = get_option( 'twitter_link', '' );
echo '<input id="twitter_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="Twitter Link" name="twitter_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($twitter_link) . '" />';
}

function linkedin_function() {
$linkedin_link = get_option( 'linkedin_link', '' );
echo '<input id="linkedin_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="LinkedIn Link" name="linkedin_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($linkedin_link) . '" />';
}

function instagram_function() {
$instagram_link = get_option( 'instagram_link', '' );
echo '<input id="instagram_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="Instagram Link" name="instagram_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($instagram_link) . '" />';
}

function youtube_function() {
$youtube_link = get_option( 'youtube_link', '' );
echo '<input id="youtube_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="YouTube Link" name="youtube_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($youtube_link) . '" />';
}
```

How do I convert the above to work in PHP OOP

```
class MY_Plugin_Social {



    public function init() {

add_action( 'admin_init', 'link_settings_api_init' );
// or should I use an array     add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'link_settings_api_init' ), 99 );
    }

public function link_settings_api_init() {
    // Add the section to general settings so we can add our
    // fields to it
    add_settings_section(
       'links_setting_section',
       'Social Links',
       'links_setting_section_callback_function',
       'general'
   );

    // Add the field with the names and function to use for our new
    // settings, put it in our new section
    add_settings_field(
       'facebook_link',
       'Facebook Link',
       'facebook_function',
       'general',
       'links_setting_section'
   );

   add_settings_field(
        'twitter_link',
        'Twitter Link',
        'twitter_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'linkedin_link',
        'Linkedn Link',
        'linkedin_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'instagram_link',
        'Instagram Link',
        'instagram_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'youtube_link',
        'YouTube Link',
        'youtube_function',
        'general',
        'links_setting_section'
    );
    // Register our setting so that $_POST handling is done for us and
    // our callback function just has to echo the <input>
    register_setting( 'general', 'facebook_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'twitter_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'linkedin_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'instagram_link' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'youtube_link' );

} // link_settings_api_init()

public function links_setting_section_callback_function() {
    echo '<p>Add Social Media Links for HSPH</p>';
}

public function facebook_function() {
$facebook_link = get_option( 'facebook_link', '' );
echo '<input id="facebook_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="Facebook Link" name="facebook_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($facebook_link) . '" />';
}

public function twitter_function() {
$twitter_link = get_option( 'twitter_link', '' );
echo '<input id="twitter_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="Twitter Link" name="twitter_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($twitter_link) . '" />';
}

public function linkedin_function() {
$linkedin_link = get_option( 'linkedin_link', '' );
echo '<input id="linkedin_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="LinkedIn Link" name="linkedin_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($linkedin_link) . '" />';
}

public function instagram_function() {
$instagram_link = get_option( 'instagram_link', '' );
echo '<input id="instagram_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="Instagram Link" name="instagram_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($instagram_link) . '" />';
}

function youtube_function() {
$youtube_link = get_option( 'youtube_link', '' );
echo '<input id="youtube_link" style="width: 35%;" type="text" title="YouTube Link" name="youtube_link" value="' . sanitize_text_field($youtube_link) . '" />';
}

}
```

I'm getting a callback error similar to Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'links_setting_section_callback_function' not found or invalid function name in /home/xyz/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 1608

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordpress plugin : settings api with OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081205/wordpress-plugin-settings-api-with-oop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass the second parameter of `add_action` or `add_filter` as array. Example
`add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'my_public_method' ] );` `$this` can be replaced by the fully qualified class name if my_public_method is a static function. Alternatively you can pass a closure as the second parameter. See example below

```
<?php
class Example()
{
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', $this->method());
    }

    public function method() {
        return function() { echo 'I am a Closure';};
    }
}
```